# Laravel "pathinfo() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given"

Tags: php, laravel, controller

```
/* My controller */
```

When i upload excel file from laravel 5.7 shows this error.
Someone can help me with this issue.

```
 public function getUpload(){
        $acessoAnalytics = AcessoAnalytics::all();

        $file = Input::file('file');
        $file_name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $file->move('files',$file_name);
        $result = Excel::import($file_name,function($reader){
            $reader->all();
        })->get();

        return view('acesso.analytics.index',compact('acessoAnalytics'));
    }
```

[Mensage error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSBlQ.png)

Comment: Obviously somewhere you're passing an object where a string is expected. Check the documentation for the functions you're using. Laravel will give you a stack trace showing exactly where the problem is.

Comment: The error is most likely in your import usage, instead of the filename, you should pass the file. I don't know which library you use, but try using the `$file` instead of the `$file_name` in your import call as a first parameter.